# Could not load file or assembly 'protobuf-net' error if I start .NET process via CreateProcess()

Tags: c#, .net, windows, runtime-error

I have created a .NET application in C# and it executes fine when I run it from console cmd window but if I tried to start the application from my own app written in C++ by calling CreateProcess(), I am getting exception as follows.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
'AppLog_NS.LogReader' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 
Could not load file or assembly 'protobuf-net, Version=1.0.0.280, Culture=neutral, 
ublicKeyToken=257b51d87d2e4d67' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot 
find the file specified.File name: 'protobuf-net, Version=1.0.0.280, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=257b51d87d2e4d67' at AppLog_NS.LogReader..cctor()
```

Here is how I call CreateProcess().

```
GetSecurityInfo(GetCurrentProcess(), SE_KERNEL_OBJECT, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &sd);
saAttr.nLength = sizeof(saAttr);
saAttr.bInheritHandle = FALSE;
saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = sd;

memset(&si, 0, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
memset(&pi, 0, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));

// Launch bootstrapper
CreateProcess(NULL, cmd_path,  &saAttr, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

FYI, Parent process and .NET application that I created both reside in the same directory and I have protobuf-net.dll in that directory as well. Otherwise, it should have failed to start properly from cmd window.

protobuf-net.dll is not in GAC and I assume that as long as it is in the same directory it should be able to locate dll and start .NET application properly. Is there anything that I need to configure or do something in this case?

The other thing to note is that FusionLog shows that PrivatePath is set to NULL and it says that 'No application configuration file found.' This is very odd to me because I also added config file to the same directory to specify PrivatePath but that does not seem to do anything, either.

So I am assuming that I need to pass certain env variable or something when I create a .NET process.

But I can't really think of any option that I need to use.
Can anyone give me some suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried passing the directory in which the application resides to the CreateProcess method (CurrentDirectory/WorkingDirectory)?

Comment: For lack of any code to look at: use ShellExecute() instead.  It is easier to get right.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried to set working directory but that did not do anything.

Comment: I found a way to fix my issue but I would appreciate if I can get some insight on it. Basically I changed the way I call CreateProcess().

Instead of giving full path for commandline args, I gave executable name for ApplicationName. 

So I called as follows: 

CreateProcess("AppLog.exe", NULL, &saAttr, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi); This worked but not sure why this works but not the other one.

Comment: this fix doesn't work in vba even with WorkingDirectory

Answer (score 0):

I know you are trying to start the .net app from a C program. A good place to look would be the source code for the .net class `Process`. It calls a private method called `StartWithCreateProcess(startInfo)` which is [available here from Microsoft](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs,c50d8ac0eb7bc0d6):

```
        [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
        [ResourceConsumption(ResourceScope.Machine, ResourceScope.Machine)]
        public bool Start() {
            Close();
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = StartInfo;
            if (startInfo.FileName.Length == 0) 
                throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString(SR.FileNameMissing));
 
            if (startInfo.UseShellExecute) {
#if !FEATURE_PAL                
                return StartWithShellExecuteEx(startInfo);
#else
                throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString(SR.net_perm_invalid_val, "StartInfo.UseShellExecute", true));
#endif // !FEATURE_PAL
            } else {
                return StartWithCreateProcess(startInfo);
            }
        }
```

This should provide you with details on how to setup the CreateProcess() call. They are doing quite a bit of setup and then calling CreateProcess() as follows:

```
                   retVal = NativeMethods.CreateProcess (
                           null,               // we don't need this since all the info is in commandLine
                           commandLine,        // pointer to the command line string
                           null,               // pointer to process security attributes, we don't need to inheriat the handle
                           null,               // pointer to thread security attributes
                           true,               // handle inheritance flag
                           creationFlags,      // creation flags
                           environmentPtr,     // pointer to new environment block
                           workingDirectory,   // pointer to current directory name
                           startupInfo,        // pointer to STARTUPINFO
                           processInfo         // pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION
                       );
```

Comparing with your invocation, I see some differences:

```
CreateProcess(NULL, cmd_path,  &saAttr, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

You can try the same type of parameters as Process.Start()'s invocation of CreateProcess() and go from there.